# How to output data with a template page without using <a> tag?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-templates

I'm working on an angularjs app, and I want to display data with a template page if possible. For example:

```
<div data-ng-view=""></div>

<input type="text" name="name" data-ng-model="post.name"/>
<input type="text" name="comment" data-ng-model="post.comment"/>
<button data-ng-click="">Post</button>
```

I usually do it by this way, but I just wondering is it possible that I could achieve it with a button?

```
<a href="#post/{{name}}">Post</a> //HTML

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/post/:name', {
        templateUrl: 'template.html', 
        controller: 'postCtrl'
    });
}]);

app.controller('postCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {  
    $scope.name = $routeParams.name;
    $scope.comment = $routeParams.comment;
});
```

When the button is clicked, the inputed data would be display in the template page like this.

```
name1: this is a comment
name2: this is another comment
```

Comment: Your question is not clear... Are you trying to do 2 way binding with click event?

Comment: Please provide full description of what exactly you are trying to do. To be honest it really seems like you need to study some basic angular tutorials such as the one on the documentation site that shows you how to use router, services, controller models etc

Comment: You are right I'm a fresh man in angular though I learnt some basic knowledge about it in my UNI.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$location.path()`:

Html:

```
<button data-ng-click="postCall()">Post</button>
```

Inject `$location` dependency in the controller as:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {  
    $scope.postCall = function() {
       $location.path("#post/" + $scope.name)
    };
});
```

[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this?

```
{{ name }}
<br>
{{ comment }}
```

In controller:

```
$scope.onClick = function () {
  $scope.name = 'this is name';
  $scope.comment = 'this is comment';
}
```